# SweetAlert при входе

Tags: php, javascript, sweetalert

Как показать модальное окно от SweetAlert при входе на сайт?

Comment: что значит при входе? при загрузке или при входе в аккаунт?

Comment: Там же на сайте SweetAlert документация есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в JS  добавь и попробуй например так:

```
function ready() {
    swal("Hello world!");
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```